# Start/Stop Window Service from ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, windows-services, security, impersonation

Is there a way to start / stop a windows service of a server in a different network

(not `\\<server name>`) from an asp.net page?

I tried using ServiceController but it's only work if it's in the same network.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Start/Stop a Windows Service from an ASP.NET app - Security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818512/how-to-start-stop-a-windows-service-from-an-asp-net-app-security-issues)

Comment: Or even better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12893735/993547

Answer (score 5):

RE: ServiceController [How to Start/Stop a Windows Service from an ASP.NET app - Security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818512/how-to-start-stop-a-windows-service-from-an-asp-net-app-security-issues?rq=1)

Anything you can do from command line or powershell can be ran from a page (assuming the app pool user has correct permissions etc)

- https://serverfault.com/questions/429426/how-can-i-connect-to-a-windows-server-using-a-command-line-interface-cli
- [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)
- [How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

Powershell is probably your best bet for managing services on a remote server though this will require the server to allow remote powershell.

- [Calling Powershell from C# (ASP.NET) - pass custom object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439935/calling-powershell-from-c-sharp-asp-net-pass-custom-object)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

and of course for the topic of powershell resetting/stopping remote services.

- http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/08/28/pstip-starting-and-stopping-services-on-remote-computers/
- [How to start/stop a service on a remote server using PowerShell - Windows 2008 & prompt for credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408448/powershell-how-to-start-stop-service-on-remote-server-windows-2008-prompt-for?rq=1)

Google is definitely your friend on this one :)

Comment: This is a post consisting of links instead of content, and that is discouraged since it adds little to no value for future visitors. Please update your answer to highlight the key parts from the references.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'd disagree as 6 of those links are on stackexchange; adding the contents of other posts would cause duplication whilst losing the context.

Comment: I understand. Please read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/245360).

Comment: @PatrickHofman we'll have to agree to disagree as this is from 3 years ago and frankly I don't care; if you want to provide the contents of other posts as an answer to a vague question feel free.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I think sharing links is also helpful and sometime is a better answer